# 2 Digit Integer Display in Proteus

Tags: display, homework, proteus

I have a homework which I am working on right now.

> Design a counter that counts 0 4 6 8 12 14 0... (mod6) and when to counter shows 14 it is going to stop and wait for 3 minutes. After 3 minutes counter is going to count 0 1 2 3 4.... 14 15 0 ... There is going to be 6.667 seconds between every count.

I created a counter which counts up to 15 but I do not know how I am going to display 2 digits. I am using Proteus and I have tried some multiple digit displays but could not figure out how they work. Since Proteus does not have a Binary-To-BCD converter (it only has the model, the configuration is not there and therefore it is not working) I believe that I need to use some kind of display integration.

Comment: that assignment says nothing about including a display

Comment: Yes, it does not indeed. I just want to display the number, because I am going to capture screenshots for every step of counter before sending the homework. And I want the display to be in the decimal format, not binary.

Comment: use a ROM then.

Comment: Alright I'll try that thank you so much.